# How to store uicollectionview selected items into single object?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

#### Background Info

I have 2 `UIcollectionView`s. The first one represents a list of Indian states and the second one shows a list of colleges.
When selecting any state in the first `UICollectionView`, the corresponding colleges list will be displayed in the second `UICollectionView`.

#### Issue

My requirement is: suppose I select 3 colleges in the state of Maharastra and 4 colleges in the state of Karnataka. I need to store the selected colleges with reference to the state name or ID.

Example:
`[Karnataka : collegeA, collegeB, collegeC, collegeD]`
`[Maharastra : collegeX, collegeY, collegeZ]`

#### Code

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if collectionView.isEqual(statesCollectionView) {
        print("Selected state Details : \(stateNamesArr[indexPath.row]) )")
        print("Selected state ID : \(stateIDsArr[indexPath.row]) )")
        selectedStateID = stateIDsArr[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        let selectedCell:collegesCollectionViewCell = collactionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)! as! ProfessionalTimesCollectionViewCell
        selectedCell.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 102/256, green: 255/256, blue: 255/256, alpha: 0.66).cgColor
        selectedCell.layer.borderWidth = 2
        selectedCell.professionalsTimeLbl.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        print("selected colleges: \(collegesArr[indexPath.row])")
        selectedCollegesArr.append(collegesArr[indexPath.row])
        var collegesDict = [String() :[Any]()]
        collegesDict = ["\(selectedStateID)" : [selectedCollegesArr]]
        print("Dict: \(collegesDict)")
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "store"?  Store the results so that you can process the data later in the app? Store the data is that you can access it next time the app is run?  Send the data to a server to be stored?

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewController holding your collection views, add a class variable that is of type `[String: [String]]`

Then in your didSelectItem at:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if collectionView.isEqual(statesCollectionView) {
        state = stateNamesArr[indexPath.item]
        print("Selected state Details : \(stateNamesArr[indexPath.row]) )")
        print("Selected state ID : \(stateIDsArr[indexPath.row]) )")
        selectedStateID = stateIDsArr[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        let selectedCell:collegesCollectionViewCell = collactionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)! as! ProfessionalTimesCollectionViewCell
        selectedCell.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 102/256, green: 255/256, blue: 255/256, alpha: 0.66).cgColor
        selectedCell.layer.borderWidth = 2
        selectedCell.professionalsTimeLbl.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        print("selected colleges: \(collegesArr[indexPath.row])")
        selectedCollegesArr.append(collegesArr[indexPath.row])

        //selectedColleges would be the [String: [String]] object -- name it whatever you want

        if selectedColleges[state] != nil {
            selectedColleges[state].append(collegesArr[indexPath.item])
        } else {
            selectedColleges[state] = collegesArr[indexPath.item]
        }

        collegesDict = ["\(selectedStateID)" : [selectedCollegesArr]]
        print("Dict: \(collegesDict)")
    }
}
```

By the way, since you are using `UICollectionView`s you should be accessing the selected element using `indexPath.item` -- `indexPath.row` is used for `UITableView`s

Comment: got the error "value of type any has no member append" at this line selectedColleges[state].append(collegesArr[indexPath.item]). What type of arrays that I need to declare? 
is this ok to declare as class variable "var selectedColleges = [String: [String]]() as! NSMutableDictionary"

Comment: it should be declared as `var selectedColleges = [String : [String]]()` this will give you a empty Swift 'dictionary' allowing you to use a `String` as the key to a array of `String`s

Comment: value of string has no member append this is the error in this line "            selectedColleges[state].append(collegesArr[indexPath.item])
"

Comment: did you declare the variable correctly?  I just used a playground to double check it: `var test = [String : [String]]()
test["testing1"] = ["Hello"]
test["testing1"]!.append("world")

for string in test["testing1"]! {
    print(string)
}`

Answer (score -2):

you can do it with Userdefaults

```
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    // This is set
    defaults.set(yourselectedThings, forKey: "selectedId")

    // Get is
    defaults.object(forKey: "selectedId")
```